# can i generate 2 consecutive values from the random module

Tags: python

my question is if i was using randint and i got `'3', '9'`, and '15' would it somehow be possible to output `'3,4' '9,10' '15,16'`. or even better if it could output lets say '9' and then '8' or '10'

if this is possible i may be able to incorporate this into my maze generator

```
end = 20
i = 0
while i < end:
    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)

    if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]:
        TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
        Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
    else:
        end += 1 
    i += 1
```

the idea is instead of a bunch of random tiles spawning on a grid there will be more connected pathways

Comment: The short answer: Yes, you can occasionally get sequential numbers from the random module.  But simply popping random walls up on a grid is a very inefficient way to build a maze.  Also, remember to `seed` the random number generator (look it up) unless you want to get the same numbers each time you run your program.

Comment: Is is possible to have a generator that gives sequences of 2 adjactent numbers? Yes it is easy. But I could not understand how this can be related with your code...

Comment: You could just write a function that gens a random number, adds or minuses 1 to it, then returns the pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
x = random.randint(1,101)
print (x,x+1)
```

I think this should help

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.